# how can i make an pgAudit installation for my PostgreSQL10?

Tags: postgresql-10

I wanted to install pgAudit on my CentOS 6 32-bit, I already installed PostgreSQL 10 + pgAdmin4 from PostgreSQL Linux run installer that I downloaded from DBEnterprise

I followed the guide from [here](https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit), here are the steps I followed :

1. `git clone https://github.com/postgres/postgres.git`
2. go into the folder by `cd postgres` and then `git checkout REL_10_STABLE`
3. `./configure` after that `make install -s`
4. `cd contrib`
5. Clone the pgAudit extension by `git clone https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit.git`
6. `cd pgaudit`
7. `git checkout REL_10_STABLE`
8. `make -s check`
9. `make install`

I'm stuck at step 8. Here's the result :

```
[root@localhost pgaudit]# make -s check
============== creating temporary instance            ==============
============== initializing database system           ==============

pg_regress: initdb failed
Examine /root/postgres/contrib/pgaudit/log/initdb.log for the reason.
Command was: "initdb" -D "/root/postgres/contrib/pgaudit/./tmp_check/data" --no-clean --no-sync > "/root/postgres/contrib/pgaudit/log/initdb.log" 2>&1
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

I opened the initdb.log at `/root/postgres/contrib/pgaudit/log/initdb.log` like how it told me to, and it says :

```
Running in no-clean mode.  Mistakes will not be cleaned up.
initdb: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.
```

So I tried it again after I logged in as postgres, here's the result :

```
bash-4.1$ make -s check
make[3]: stat: ../../src/include/utils/errcodes.h: Permission denied
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: utils/: Not a directory
make[3]: *** [../../src/include/utils/errcodes.h] Error 1
make[2]: *** [submake-errcodes] Error 2
make[1]: *** [submake-libpgport] Error 2
make: *** [submake] Error 2
```

I'm really new to both Linux and PostgreSQL, so I don't know why it failed and what is the solution for this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can try with `sudo make -s check`

Comment: the result is exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

Look like your db user not having a login shell.

You can try with:

```
sudo -u postgres psql template
```

Or:

```
sudo -u postgres bash
```